# Adding a configurable form to an entity display

Tags: 8, entities

I am trying to attach a configurable form with multiple fields (including text fields) to an event product entity display page so end users can enter registration information into fields on the event product page.  The idea is to allow a store owner to create several different sets of registration forms for different types of event products.  Does anyone know of a way to do this or of a Drupal 8 contributed module where something similar has been done that could be used as a reference example?

I thought there might be a way to use a custom entity bundle for the form and simply add an entity reference field to the parent entity.  Since the list of fields varies by product, the form has to have fields that can be customized by the user.

This in not a Commerce-specific question.  I just want to know how to add a site owner configurable form to an entity.

Comment: It depends on how much coding you're willing to do. The fastest way would be using webform module + entity reference field. And to display the webform..I guess paragraphs(I've never used them so dunno)?

Comment: Thanks Ivan, it's for what is intended to be a contrib module.  I will try out the webform module and possibly use it as an example to get the functionality I need.